# Wake On LAN - wake laptop from sleep when its lid is closed?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, wake-on-lan, lid

I have set up Wake On LAN and I am able to wake my laptop when it's sleeping, but only when the laptop's lid is up, not when it's down/closed.

There will be cases where my laptop will be sleeping *whilst* the lid is down/closed and I want to awaken it in this state.

I know that I can control what happens *when* I close the lid, but I want to be able to change the relevant settings (if there are any) to make the laptop wake up *whilst* the lid is down/closed.

It seems possible (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474516/wake-on-lan-a-laptop-when-the-lid-is-closed) but my laptop is running Windows 10.

I have not been able to find an answer on similar threads:

[Windows Wake-on-LAN from Sleep on Laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1638630/windows-wake-on-lan-from-sleep-on-laptop)

[Waking an acer laptop from sleep with the lid closed](https://superuser.com/questions/1695860/waking-an-acer-laptop-from-sleep-with-the-lid-closed?rq=1)

[How to wake a sleeping laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/714871/how-to-wake-a-sleeping-laptop)

[Power on laptop without opening lid](https://superuser.com/questions/222472/power-on-laptop-without-opening-lid/222513#222513)

[How do I turn on laptop (Asus R1F) with lid closed?](https://superuser.com/questions/75310/how-do-i-turn-on-laptop-asus-r1f-with-lid-closed)

Short of ripping my laptop apart to disable the mechanism that prevents waking/power when the lid is down, I'm at a loss...

Laptop is Acer EX2540-55GG Model N16C1 if that helps.

thank you

Comment: You might want to try to [disable the lid switch actions](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-change-lid-close-action-to-do-nothing-in-windows-11/). While this usually works in linux, I don't know if it also will work on windows

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear in my original post, I have edited it. Thank you for trying to help.